# Best way to initialize GUI in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I want to set up several ui elements based on system information at the time of the application start up (i.e. this is info not known a priori so to set it statically in the css or the fxml file).
Is the controller constructor the best place to do this?
A first consideration was to do that either on the `start()` or `init()` methods of the main class that extends Application but it seems the set up is rather preventing programmer from easily accessing ui elements all the way down the node hierarchy. (which on the other hand is extremely easy in the respective controller through the @FXML injection)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of work you need done. If you need anything that relies on your application's stage, then perform it in the start method. If not, then it can be performed in the constructor, init, or start methods. Bear in mind that the launching mechanism expects Application subclasses to provide a no-arg constructor, so if you incorporate startup logic there, then avoid requiring constructor parameters.

However, if you're going to use a controller (which I would recommend), then this logic should occur in its initialize method, not in your application class.

If you need a reference to the stage from the controller, then you can find many such solutions to passing the reference to the controller here on SO, such as making the stage reference public and static in your application class, or having such a field in your controller that can be set from your application's start method.