# Initializing in javafx controller

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am building application using javafx fxml project in netbeans. 
As part of it I am printing a node in the controller. For that I am changing the node layout, so that it can fit in half page. Now after printing, how do I go back to the original layout. More specifically, is there a way to initialize all settings. My expertise in Javafx and Java is limited to cut/paste :( so appreciate if a code example is given. The link [Best way to initialize GUI in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181740/best-way-to-initialize-gui-in-javafx) seem to contain the answer but I am not able to understand it.

```
public void print(final Node node) {
Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER,   PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
double width = node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
double height = node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() /(2* node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight());
node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null) {
boolean success = job.printPage(node);
if (success) {
job.endJob();
}
}

 node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(width, height)); //This is not working

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to re-initialize everything; you just need to undo the changes you made for the printing. To do this, keep a reference to the scale transform and remove it when you are done:

I.e. replace

```
node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));
```

with

```
Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleY);
node.getTransforms().add(scale);
```

and replace

```
node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(width, height));
```

with

```
node.getTransforms().remove(scale);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working beautifully :). One more question. Is there a simple way to initialize the entire form like running the application again from Controller.    

  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Billbook");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }